# Javascript childnodes don't display correctly

Tags: javascript, undefined

I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            ul{
                list-style-type: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="myTemplateId">
            <li>{name}</li>
            <li>{age}</li>
            <li>{name}</li>
            <li>{age}</li>
        </ul>
        <button onclick="generate()">Generate Html</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function generate (people) {
                var list = document.querySelectorAll('#myTemplateId li');
                console.log(list[0].innerHTML);
                var index = 0;
                for(var li in list) {

                    console.log(li.innerHTML);
                }
            }
            function Person (name, age) {
                this.name = name;
                this.age = age;
            }
            var pesho = new Person('Pesho', 15);
            var gosho = new Person('Gosho', 27);
            var people = [pesho, gosho];
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The first log is fine. It logs the li elements's innerHtml. However all the logs in the for in loop log undefined. Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

Comment: Change `console.log(li.innerHTML)` to `console.log(li)` and see what you get...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `li` in the for loop is an index, not the actual element in the array. This is the correct code:

```
for(var index in list) {
    console.log(list[index].innerHTML);
}
```

But a better way to iterate through the list is:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(list, function(li, index) {
    console.log(li.innerHTML);
});
```

You can't call `forEach` directly on the `list` variable, because list is an instance of `NodeList` which doesn't have a `forEach` method.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it. Though there are still 2 undefineds after all the li elements.

Comment: Updated my answer. You can see, that the value of `list` is `[li, li, li, li, item: function]`. This is because `list` is not an array, but an instance of `NodeList`. Added an example how to iterate through the list.

Comment: You can find more details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

Answer (score 0):

When using `for(var li in list)` it loops through all the properties in the list. This means that the length and *proto* properties are also looped though, these does not have `innerHTML` so it will return undefined here.

This is my suggestion:

```
function generate(people) {
    var list = document.querySelectorAll('#myTemplateId li'),
        listLen = list.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < listLen; i++) {
        console.log(list[i].innerHTML);
    }
}

function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
var pesho = new Person('Pesho', 15);
var gosho = new Person('Gosho', 27);
var people = [pesho, gosho];
```